# Parsing JSON object with embedded 'onclick' event in android

Tags: android, json

I have following JSON file and need to parse it, and call relevant function mentioned when corresponding event occurs.

```
{"menu": {
     "id": "file",
     "value": "File",
         "popup": {
         "menuitem": [
             {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
             {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
             {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

for example, I have to populate New, Open and Close in a combobox and call function CreateNewDoc() when user selects 'new' and so on.

What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks
Bsengar

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: Have a look at [tag:droidquery] for help with parsing JSON and setting up event listeners.